# Rails html put value from hash

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Kind of easy question that for a reason i couldnt handle.
on my server side i am saving a hash:

```
@profile = {"goals" => goals, "won" => result["success"][0]["won"]}
```

if i am printing to server log console

```
puts @profile["goals"]
```

its perfectly printing it.

how can i print the value of goals on the view itself? the following didnt work for me

```
<%= @profile.goals %>
<%= @profile[goals] %>
<%= @profile{goals} %>
```

thanks

Comment: <%= @profile['goals'] %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below :

```
  <%= @profile['goals'] %>
```

As `@profile` hash has a key as `'goals'`.

Comment: it keeps saying

    undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

even though on the server when i put @profile it puts {"goals"=>"0"} correctly

Comment: @Meschiany What is saying?

Comment: My bad, I feel so stupid, it returns from another method, i should return it with json.